# VS 2019 suddenly stopped allowing me to debug Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am running VS 2019.  I'm running a Asp.Net MVC web project, its on .Net 4.6. I've been debugging JavaScript successfully until is suddenly quit working.   It just skips passed all break points.  I have doubled checked and I have the line "Enable JavaScript for Asp.Net.. " checked, [image: Enable JavaScript Debugging for Asp.Net(chrome... Checked] but still nothing.   If I switch the Chrome and try it. It will stop but at some random spot and doesn't allow stepping through.  I I also checked and verified that  Bundle optimization was turned off.
`BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`
 but it doesn't seem to make a difference either way. 
I did manage to get it working in Chrome by un-checking the "Enable JavaScript Debugging for Asp.Net" line and then using the developer tools but why did it suddenly stop in Visual Studio 2019.  I even tried resetting Visual Studio back to all defaults and that didn't work. Lastly I tried a full uninstall and reinstall but still nothing?   I've also added the old tried and true "debugger;" line and it still ignores it.  Any thoughts?